# jQuery bouncing image

Tags: jquery, image

I have a requirement, wherein, the client want's an image to bounce, currently I'm using this

```
$(window).ready(function () {
           $('#homePageImage').stop()
           .animate(
            {
                 height: '370px'
            },
            {    queue: false,
                 duration: 1000,
                 easing: 'easeOutBounce' });
             });
```

But, the client wants the entire image to "fall down" and bounce, how can it be done?

Thank you !

Comment: Sometimes, the developer just has to stand up to the client when they want something silly. This may be one of those times =D

Comment: I wish i could downvote comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking mate really...

here are two potential solutions:

1. Include Jquery ui - easeOutBounce is a jquery ui component and not included in stock jquery.
2. Make #homePageImage `position: absolute` and animate the `top:` value not the `height:`. That way the image will fall down and bounce. You'll have to start with the image at `top: -*height of the image*` so its just off the screen and then animate it to `top: *where you want it*` with the easing `easeOutBounce`. :)

Comment: cool :) sorry, I didn't know whether you meant that it wasn't bouncing at all, or (after a couple of re-reads) that you meant it didn't look like it was dropping and bouncing right. :)